# Programmatically swipe UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

Is there any way to programmatically trigger the equivalent of swiping left on a UITableViewCell that has edit actions? This is different from simply `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]` as that method sets the entire table into editing mode and shows the insert/delete left accessory view and/or reorder controls rather than the edit actions for a single row.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle` from [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:). And return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` for the cell you want to swipe. Use `func reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)` to reload that cell when you want to trigger the swipe.